# shell sript to read source file and use the key in the script

Tags: command-line, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
source /data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini
var=$($1path)
echo $var
```

---

`conf.ini` is the config file which has `LSTpath=/data/bb/loader`

I get below below error. Where am I going wrong.

```
./file LST
 line 8: LSTpath: command not found
```

Comment: Please don't change your question. After your changes, the error don't match your code and you have a completely different question.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it using [`eval`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/eval.1posix.html).

```
eval - construct command by concatenating arguments
```

Modify your script as follows:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
source /data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini
eval var='$'"$1"path
echo $var
```

then run it like this:

```bsh
$ ./foo LST
/data/bb/loader
```

where,

```bsh
$ cat /data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini
LSTpath=/data/bb/loader
```

Comment: I don't like `eval`, but your solution is the shorter one  **;)** +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, I don't like `eval` **;)**

Your `var=$($1path)` executes the first parameter of your script (`$1`) concatenated with `path` as a command. Therefore the error.

Your new script

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(awk -F= '/^'"$1"'path/ {print $2}' /data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini)
echo "$var"
```

Your `/data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini`

```
LSTpath=/data/bb/loader
```

---

*Example*

```
$ ./foo LST
/data/bb/loader
```

Comment: I agree `eval` has some drawbacks. In this situation use of `eval`  is the simplest solution. +1 for your alternate `eval` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`, eval :(

Assuming `source` is used to load the variables to get path from conf.ini

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`grep $1 /data/output/QAScripts/conf.ini | grep -oP '[^'$1'path\=](.*)'`
echo $var
```

conf.ini

```
LSTpath=/data/bb/loader
#following added to demonstrate
LSApath=/data/bb/A
LSBpath=/data/bb/B
LSCpath=/data/bb/C
```

Output:
Displays according to arg var

```
root@controller:~# ./script.sh LST
/data/bb/loader
root@controller:~# ./script.sh LSA
/data/bb/A
root@controller:~# ./script.sh LSB
/data/bb/B
root@controller:~# ./script.sh LSC
/data/bb/C
root@controller:~#
```

Thank You :)